# Broken Pipe error when using pip to install pycrypto on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, gcc, pip, pycrypto

I am attempting to install pycrypto (version 2.3) on OS X via pip.  I am getting a "Broken pipe" error when the compiler attempts to compile MD2.c.  I get a very similar error when using easy_install.

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$ sudo pip install pycrypto
Password:
Downloading/unpacking pycrypto
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycrypto
Installing collected packages: pycrypto
  Running setup.py install for pycrypto
    warning: GMP library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
    building 'Crypto.Hash.MD2' extension
    gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/src/MD2.o
    /usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
    Installed assemblers are:
    /usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
    /usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
    src/MD2.c:134: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
    compilation terminated.
    lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//cc47qHNI.out (No such file or directory)
    error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/damusin/tmp/pycrypto/pycrypto-2.3/build/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-W6xQ61-record/install-record.txt:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

warning: GMP library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.

building 'Crypto.Hash.MD2' extension

gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c src/MD2.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/src/MD2.o

/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed

Installed assemblers are:

/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64

/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386

src/MD2.c:134: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe

compilation terminated.

lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//cc47qHNI.out (No such file or directory)

error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/damusin/tmp/pycrypto/pycrypto-2.3/build/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /tmp/pip-W6xQ61-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/admin/.pip/pip.log
bash-3.2$ 
bash-3.2$
```

I attempted to install this package using mac ports with the command "sudo port install py26-crypto", and looks to install smoothly but then it tells me that the pycrypto package is missing when running the command "fab" (Fabric).

I attempted using the "ARCHFLAGS" command recommended in answer by YH Wong here but no luck:
https://superuser.com/questions/259278/python-2-6-1-pycrypto-2-3-pypi-package-broken-pipe-during-build

I am using Mac OS X 10.6.7 with python 2.6.6 and XCode is installed.

Comment: Give ActivePython a try (no need to compile modules yourself): http://code.activestate.com/pypm/pycrypto/

Answer (score 65):

If you have installed Xcode 4, try setting `ARCHFLAGS` before calling `pip` or `easy_install`:

```
sudo bash
export ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64'
pip ...
```

The problem is that Xcode 4 has removed support for `-arch ppc` but the system Python 2.6 on Mac OS X 10.6 expects to build universal C extension modules with all three architectures.  And if you define the environment variable prior to the sudo command, it will likely not be exported through to the sudo environment.

Comment: You can simply write `sudo ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' pip ...`.

Comment: There's some info about this on the oficial docs: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/overview.html#compiling-on-os-x

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 5.1

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip2.7 install pycrypto
```

Comment: This did it for me. Spent a larger part of the day trying to find a fix