# Installing Lunatic Python on MacOS System

Tags: python, lua

I am currently trying to get the lunatic python package running on my mac operating system. My  problem is, there are several errors occurring while running LunPy's makefile. 
Can somebody tell me how to properly set up the Lunatic Python package?

Thanks in advance!

```
lunatic-python-1.0 $ make
python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'lua-python' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c src/pythoninlua.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/src/pythoninlua.o -rdynamic
src/pythoninlua.c: In function ‘py_convert’:
src/pythoninlua.c:74: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘PyString_AsStringAndSize’ from incompatible pointer type
src/pythoninlua.c: In function ‘py_object_tostring’:
src/pythoninlua.c:335: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘PyString_AsStringAndSize’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/libexec/gcc/powerpc-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/as: assembler (/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as or /usr/bin/../local/libexec/gcc/darwin/ppc/as) for architecture ppc not installed
Installed assemblers are:
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/x86_64/as for architecture x86_64
/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/darwin/i386/as for architecture i386
src/pythoninlua.c: In function ‘py_convert’:
src/pythoninlua.c:74: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘PyString_AsStringAndSize’ from incompatible pointer type
src/pythoninlua.c: In function ‘py_object_tostring’:
src/pythoninlua.c:335: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘PyString_AsStringAndSize’ from incompatible pointer type
src/pythoninlua.c: At top level:
src/pythoninlua.c:611: fatal error: error writing to -: Broken pipe
compilation terminated.
src/pythoninlua.c: In function ‘py_convert’:
src/pythoninlua.c:74: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘PyString_AsStringAndSize’ from incompatible pointer type
src/pythoninlua.c: In function ‘py_object_tostring’:
src/pythoninlua.c:335: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘PyString_AsStringAndSize’ from incompatible pointer type
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/B3/B3c7Jc4xGW0iy57FwnJ13++++TI/-Tmp-//ccwG6Ppf.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the Apple-supplied Python 2.6 on Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and you've also installed the new Xcode 4.  You need to set the `ARCHFLAGS` environment variable as [explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5944332/broken-pipe-error-when-using-pip-to-install-pycrypto-on-mac-os-x/5944375#5944375).

Comment: I started bash and entered 'sudo ARCHFLAGS='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' make' - however, the error-log keeps on appearing